# PHP - Get Value from another website

Tags: php, regex, curl

Well, I want to extract a value from another website(members number).
This is it: https://ffs-gaming.com/clans.php?clanid=1264

```
<?php
$CurlStart = curl_init();
curl_setopt ($CurlStart, CURLOPT_URL, "https://ffs-gaming.com/clans.php?
clanid=1264");
curl_setopt ($CurlStart, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt ($CurlStart, CURLOPT_REFERER, $url);
curl_setopt ($CurlStart, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; 
Windows NT 6.1; nl; rv:1.9.1.11) Gecko/20100701 Firefox/3.5.11");
curl_setopt ($CurlStart, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
curl_setopt ($CurlStart, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
$source = curl_exec ($CurlStart);
curl_close ($CurlStart);

$a=preg_match("/>Members.*.\n.*.>([0-9]*)</",$source,$b);
$members = $b[1];
echo "Members: $members";
?>
```

That's the code, I found it on a forum, modified it but it doesn't work.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: before doing all that scraping, do they have an api that you can use? much better using that route. if not, consider using `DOMDocument` instead

Comment: I think the website not allow you the get data by that code

Comment: Have you checked to make sure CURL is returning some HTML? What does `$source` contain?